# Saving a text file from external source to my app Objective C

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

Abstract Question here I guess

I have an idea for an app that parses .txt files and outputs info based on what is contained in the file. My question is how would I go about getting the text file into my app for example if the text file was attached to an email?

This is the only hurdle I have to get clear in my mind before I begin.
So here's a real life scernaio -

I have email with text file, I want to open my app and say import file.
I need to get that text file from my email into the app so I can manipulate it.

Not sure this is possible, hopefully somebody can let me know or suggest a workaround.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register your app to [open a particular file type](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010411-SW1) and ensure the attached file is identified as one of these file types (i.e. using mime type).  You will probably want to use a unique file extension, other than `.txt`.

Comment: Gotcha so after doing this I would go to my Gmail app for example and hit the share button (not sure that's it's name) and my app would show up in the list of apps that appear? why a unique file extension if the files are .txt?

Comment: Yeah that sounds about right.  I think a unique file extension makes it obvious that this file is more than just text.